# How to dynamically size a textbox to be the width of a certain number of characters?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have some text boxes that are only allowed to contain a certain number of characters, e.g. 12 or 14 in most cases.

Is it possible to dynamically size the text boxes to be the width of 12 characters or 14 characters, depending on the word?

Comment: Can't you just set the [MaxLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlength(v=vs.100).aspx) property? I think the default `Width` of a `TextBox` is `Auto`, so it will auto-size based on the width of the `Text`

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if i understand your question right, but for a given string you might set the `Text` and `Width` property of a TextBox simultaneously like the sample method below.

It creates a [FormattedText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms634943) object from the given text and all the font-related properties of the TextBox. Then it assigns an empty string to the TextBox to get the "empty" width (which should also be possible by adding left and right padding, left and right border thickness etc). Finally the method assigns the `Text` property and sets the `Width` to the empy width plus the width of the FormattedText.

```
public void SetTextAndWidth(TextBox textBox, string text)
{
    Typeface typeface = new Typeface(
        textBox.FontFamily, textBox.FontStyle, textBox.FontWeight, textBox.FontStretch);

    FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText(text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        FlowDirection.LeftToRight, typeface, textBox.FontSize, Brushes.Black);

    if (textBox.HorizontalAlignment == HorizontalAlignment.Stretch)
    {
        textBox.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    }

    textBox.Text = "";
    double emptyWidth = textBox.ActualWidth;

    textBox.Text = text;
    textBox.Width = formattedText.Width + emptyWidth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's always the [TextRenderer.MeasureText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sy6awsb.aspx) method.

So long as you don't mind using a forms DLL.

Or the graphic library helper method, [Graphics.MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bt8ty58.aspx).

You can then use this info to do all sorts of sizing, check out the examples in the MSDN entries.